# Javascript constructor and prototype issue

Tags: javascript, object, prototype

I have the following code which I am confused why when I define a prototype of property 'name' it comes out as '40' and not 'fred'? what is going on inside javascript? this seems like a simple question but one that I am confused about. Thanks!

```
function Product(id){
    this.id = id
    this.name = id + 20
}

Product.prototype.name = 'fred';
var p = new Product(20);
console.log(p.name);
```

Comment: Well, you set it to `40` inside the constructor - shadowing the value that would be inherited from the prototype.

Comment: thanks both of you, this seemed such an odd question when I posed it to myself as I don't normally get into a situation when I use the same name of a property on both the prototype of a constructor and within the constructor! thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you did `this.name = id + 20`.

`p.name` will find the `name` property in the instance first, if not found, then try to find in the prototype.

```
function Product(id){
    this.id = id
}

Product.prototype.name = 'fred';
var p = new Product(20);
console.log(p.name); // then it will be fred
```

Comment: what is happening in javascript behind the scenes? can you explain please?